# Passing Session - Username - into mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am struggling with this...I have created a custom login/registration and I am expanding it with a profile page for my users.

On my page I can see the username by using, this is very early stages.

```
$_SESSION['username']
```

I have used it in a form:

```
<p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>!</p>
<p>
<form method="POST" action="./includes/save_profile.php" >
Username:<input type = "text" name="username" id "title"/><br>
Title: <input type = "text" name="title" id="title"/><br>
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/><br>
Address 1: <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1"/><br>
Address 2: <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2"/><br>
Address 3: <input type="text" name="address3" id="address3"/><br>
Country: <input type="text" name="country" id="country"/><br>
Post Code: <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode"/><br>
Telephone: <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone"/><br>
Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes"><p></p>
</form>
<?php else : ?>
```

my save_profile.php contains:

```
// include stuff here

$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$title=$_POST["title"];
$firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
$address1=$_POST["address1"];
$address2=$_POST["address2"];
$address3=$_POST["address3"];
$country=$_POST["country"];
$postcode=$_POST["postcode"];
$telephone=$_POST["telephone"];
$age=$_POST["age"];


$save_profile_query = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET title = ?,firstname = ?, lastname = ?, address1 = ?, address2 = ?, address3 = ?, country = ?, postcode = ?, telephone = ?, age = ? WHERE username = ?");

if (!$save_profile_query)
{
print $save_profile_query->error;
}

$save_profile_query->bind_param('sssssssssss',$title,$firstname, $lastname, $address1, $address2, $address3, $country, $postcode, $telephone, $age, $username);

if ($save_profile_query->execute())
{
print "Record Updated";
}
else{
print $save_profile_query->error;
}
```

I will eventually want to be able to load the profile when the page opens, allow them to edit it and then submit changes...i'll have to google how to do it.  Baby steps now as I learn how it all works.

When I hardcode a username it works.  What can I not grab the session in the same way as the form fields?

I've gone through some tutorials, w3schools and some stack exchange and by all accounts it should work?  I did try and include it within the query but that failed as well.

Comment: I'm not going to ask about `session_start();`, or have I?

Comment: not unless that should be on save_profile.php - everything I read suggests it shouldn't be?  Then again everything I read assumes I know everything about php/mysql when I don't

Comment: All pages containing sessions MUST contain `session_start();`

Comment: well I also realised I was using the wrong include db connection.  Guess I should delete this!?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` also, you might need it later on.

Comment: ok, put it in an answer and I'll tick it for you...i knew it was something obvious!

Comment: It's ok, thanks for the offer. I don't put in answers anymore. I'm just glad this got resolved, cheers.